# how to load different spring properties for different environment

Tags: spring, properties, placeholder

I have two properties files. The main.properties file has a field defined

environment=DEV

---

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${catalina.home}/conf/main.properties</value>
        <value>WEB-INF/project.${environment}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

However, I got this:
Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/project.${environment}.properties]

Does any one know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? If I'm not mistaken, the values are substituted by a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and the property files have to be loaded before the substitutions are done.

One offtopic comment: starting with Spring 3.1 it is recommended to use `<context:property-placeholder />` which relies on a different implementation class.